how to use more than one file in htaccess file?
I can't use more than one file in htaccess file for password protection
<Files "startside-int.html">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile "/customers/a/1/e/korevi.no/httpd.www/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user

<Files "referater.html">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile "/customers/a/1/e/korevi.no/httpd.www/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user

I expected that both html files should be password protected

You seem to have a nested Files in your code which can be confusing. here is what i believe should happen
<Files "startside-int.html">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password Protected Area"
    AuthUserFile "/customers/a/1/e/korevi.no/httpd.www/.htpasswd"
    Require valid-user
</Files>

<Files "referater.html">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password Protected Area"
    AuthUserFile "/customers/a/1/e/korevi.no/httpd.www/.htpasswd"
    Require valid-user
</Files>

I ensured that i closed each 
